# Novel set in a dystopian future where everyone was color-blind by mandated ingestion of medicine

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia

From what I remember, in the spring of 2007, I was reading a novel in class (5th grade) about a future where everyone was color-blind by mandated ingestion of medicine. And that no one was allowed to engage in sexual reproduction only certain classes of *genetically acceptable males* were allowed to mate with other women. No emotions were allowed. No fun. No nothing but academics and community service. Not even religion.

At the end of the novel, two siblings escaped from the oppressive gray world they lived in and went into the forest for months and evaded capture from authorities. At long last, they found themselves seeing colors as the medicine begins wearing off. They see another city down the street full of beauty and freedom. It seemed that the city was a parody of New York.

I don't know if it was a localized area that was part of some cult or some kind of interdimensional traversing. But this novel seems interesting.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a sequel to *The Giver* but the three other books at https://www.vulture.com/2014/08/heres-what-happens-in-the-other-giver-books.html don't match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [*The Giver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver) (1993) by Lois Lowry

> Jonas struggles with concepts of all the new emotions and things introduced to him: whether they are inherently good, evil, or in between, and whether it is even possible to have one without the other. The Community lacks any color, memory, climate, or terrain, all in an effort to preserve structure, order, and a true sense of equality beyond personal individuality.
>
> [...]
>
> Jonas, a 12-year-old boy, lives in a Community isolated from all except a few similar towns, where everyone from small infants to the Chief Elder has an assigned role. With the annual Ceremony of Twelve upcoming, he is nervous, for there he will be assigned his life's work. He seeks reassurance from his father, a Nurturer (who cares for the new babies, who are genetically engineered; thus, Jonas's parents are not biologically related to him), and his mother, an official in the Department of Justice. He is told that the Elders, who assign the children their careers, are always right.

Comment: Aw man... I should have guessed it. But I got caught up on the "siblings" bit.